# derivate $f(x) = x\sin(3 x)\cdot e^{2 x^2}$

Tags: derivatives

How to derivate: $f(x) = x\sin(3 x)\cdot e^{2x^2}$?
I tried to divide it in two functions, 
$h(x)=x\sin(3x)$
$g(x)= e^{2 x^2}$
and do $h'x+g'h=
e^{2 x^2}(\sin(3 x)+3\cos(3x)+4xe^{2 x^2}(x\sin(3 x))$

Comment: please learn how to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) to typeset the question, begin by surrounding mathematical object by the dollar signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

- You intend to compute $h'\color{red}g + g'h.$
- Note that we have $h'(x)=\sin(3x)+3\color{red}x \cos(3x)$
- Also check out for whether your brackets match.
- You might like to factor out $e^{2x^2}$ for simplification.

Comment: Hi Siong and thank you. You wrote ''Note that we have h′(x)=sin(3x)+3xcos(3x)'' why is that?

Comment: @Dovendyr Because $h$  itself is a product, hence again the product rule applies. More over, the seconds factor of $h$ is a composite function, hence the chain rule applies

Comment: Okay, I try again! But is it the right way to go?

Comment: I got $$e(2x^2)(sin3x+3x(cos3x))+4xe^(2x^2)(sin(3x))$$

Comment: Use ^ and curly braces to use superscript. You are very close, you have copied the $h$ term wrongly, it should be $x\sin(3x)$ rather than $\sin(3x)$.

Comment: Could it be $$e^{2x^{2}}(3xcos(3x)+sin(3x))+4xe^{2x^2}(xsin(3x))$$?

Comment: Sorry I just edited, there was a parenthesis too much. THANK YOU @SiongThyeGoh, you're a star!

Comment: It seems correct. You might want to factorize $e^{2x^2}$ for simplification. you are welcome.

Comment: Ok, I will, I'm just so glad that it was right... Can you please help me with another derivative?

Comment: I just see this. I was asleep, you can always post a new question. welcome to MSE.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

For this kind of problems, in which only products, quotients, powers, exponentials are involved, logarithmic differentiation makes life easier.

$$y=x \, \sin(3x) \, e^{2x^2} \implies \log(y)=\log(x)+\log(\sin(3x))+2x^2$$ Differentiate both sides
$$\frac{y'} y=\frac 1x+\frac{3 \cos(3x)}{\sin(3x)}+4x$$ Now, use
$$y'=y \times \left(\frac{y'} y\right)=x \, \sin(3x) \, e^{2x^2}\left(\frac 1x+\frac{3 \cos(3x)}{\sin(3x)}+4x \right)$$ and simplify as much as you can.

Comment: This looks brilliant but I don't understand differentiation, I don't think we learned this step!

Comment: @Dovendyr. Then, try to remember this when you learn the derivative of a logarithm.

Comment: Sorry! This little I know, it's 1/logaritm. But you put log on the function, and then, why did you do y´/y? I never saw that before.